# Layer not visible when saving for web

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two files with (among other things) a logo is placed.
When saving the file for web (JPG, PNG,..) the logo is not visible, it's as if that specific layer is just hidden.

What could be wrong with the layer or path? When saving it as PDF, it's still visible.

This is how the file looks like in Illustrator:
[image]

In the export dialog, I chose JPG and "use artboards". As you can see the "V" dissapears:
[image]

Comment: Hi Maarten, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please clarify a bit? What settings do you use for export, what kind of file is the logo etc.. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator, switch to `View > Overprint Preview` (or press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) - after doing this, does your logo disappear again?

If yes, then your logo is set to overprint. Change this by selecting the logo, and then checking the `Transparency` and `Attributes` panels to make sure the transparency mode is ***not*** Multiply, and neither of the Overprint attributes are checked. It should look like this:

[image: overprint off]

**NOTE:** The `Overprint Stroke` on mine is greyed out because the selection does not have any stroke. If your logo does have objects with strokes, that box should be available, but should not be checked.

Comment: Good catch.. just be certain to turn **off** overprint preview before using Save for Web. If it's on Save for Web does odd things. In fact, simply having overprint preview on *could* cause items to disappear in the Save for Web dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I wasn't aware of that issue. Good to know.

Comment: Overprint Fill was checked. Unchecking the box did indeed fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a logo that was **placed** from another folder make sure it is still saved on the same location and it wasn't removed or replaced.
Also try file>export>choose png or jpeg and if you need it check the "use artboard" checkbox.

Now that I see the designs I have another idea but it's a bit extreme.
If you logo is a path use the divide tool (in the pathfinder window) to cut it out of the gradient background so instead of having a gradient background with a white logo on top you have a gradient square that the logo is cut out of it.:
[image]

Comment: It was copied from another file, so it's not placed.
I can't select PNG when exporting.. JPG is available and gives the same result.

Comment: edited my answer - try that

Comment: That would work indeed, but that would also make it difficult to move the logo if I wanted to?

Comment: no really - just select all of the relevant points with the direct selection tool (the white arrow)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the problem was that the layer was selected as "template". If you look through the layers menu you can see the "eye" icon for each visible layer. The missing layers I found had the "box" indicating they were selected as "template". I selected the layer and then the menu options for that layer and unchecked "template". Worked for me!